# On a congruence for the number of finite topologies

Tags: general-topology, number-theory, reference-request

I am making search about "On a congruence for the number of finite topologies". I have found a [paper](https://eudml.org/doc/189640). I guess it is written in Russian.

How can I find English version of this paper ?

I am also interested in other papers related to this topic.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Given a set $X$ with $n$ elements, let $T(n)$ and $T_0(n)$ be the number of the different topologies which can be defined on $X$ and the number of the different $T_0$ topologies which can be defined on $X$, respectivly.  There is no closed formula known for $T(n)$ and $T_0(n)$. I am looking for known congruence  relation for these sequences.

Comment: Have you checked to see whether there is any information about $T(n)$ and $T_0(n)$ in the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, oeis.org?

Comment: Also, I think that Russian paper is available in English translation at http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01094365 (but it looks like you only get the first page free).

Comment: So, have you followed up on my suggestions?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: The links are http://oeis.org/A000798 and http://oeis.org/A001035 . But I could not find my tpics in the list.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I need free version of the springer's page :)

Comment: A good library can get you that article on interlibrary loan.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I should find a library having this article right ?

Comment: @mesel: First, check your university library catalogue. If they do not have the article, you should go to your university library (assuming that you are a student or an instructor) and ask about the inter-library loan. Give the article information to the person responsible for the interlibrary loan and they will do the rest, like figuring out which library has this article, etc.

Comment: Even a library that isn't a university library can probably get things on interlibrary loan, if you give them all the bibliographic information.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: @ studiosus Thank you I will try, if I could not find the paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, an English translation can be found [here](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01094365). (If you provide me with your email adress, I will send this paper to you.) As for other papers, the paper you mention contains a great deal of further references (the list of references is freely available on the springer page), e.g. concerning the asymptotic behaviour of $T(n)$, $T_0(n)$ and related questions.